# Passing a list to a JSON file in C#

Tags: c#, json

I want to write to and read from a JSON file.

> I use the Newtonsoft.Json package

I have a list containing an object

```
private List<LinkElement> links = new List<LinkElement>();
```

the object structure is

```
public class LinkElement
{
public LinkElement(string link, string key, string description, string type, string[] tags)
{
       Link = link;
       Description = description;
       Type = type;
       Tags = tags;
}

public string Link { get; set; }

public string Key { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

public string Type { get; set; }

public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}
```

So when **reading** from the file I would go for

```
string data = File.ReadAllText(path);
links = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LinkElement>>(data);
```

and when **writing** to the file I would go for

```
string newData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(links);
File.WriteAllText(path, newData);
```

but it seems lists are not the right element to take. Dictionaries would be possible.

Could someone help me out passing the list to the JSON file?

Comment: What are you expecting the input and output to be? If you're (de)serializing a list, then it should be an array of items.

Comment: Can you tell us more, what you are specifically trying to do?

Comment: i just realised that I posted the exact same thing as you, it should work fine... what is your issue, do you get a error?

Comment: why "lists are not the right element to take", what are you trying to achieve? JsonConvert.SerializeObject accept object as parameter so you can pass whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do.

First of all you do not need the constructor in your model.

```
public class LinkElement
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public LinkElementInfo Info { get; set; }
}

public class LinkElementInfo 
{
   public string Link { get; set; }

   public string Description { get; set; }

   public string Type { get; set; }

   public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}

//Example Data
Dictionary<string, LinkElementInfo> links = new Dictionary<string, LinkElementInfo>()
{
  {'a',{...}}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the `Key` from `LinkElement` and use it as the key value in a Dictionary, like this:

```
public class LinkElement
{
  public string Link { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}

private Dictionary<string, LinkElement> links = new Dictionary<string, LinkElement>();
```

To store items in `links`, use this:

```
links.Add(key1, linkElement1);
links.Add(key2, linkElement2);
```

(Or if each LinkElement needs to know *its own Key*, then leave it in the `class` and use this to add: `links.Add(linkElement1.Key, linkElement1);` etc)

To write it, your code stays the same.
To read it, your code changes a little:

```
string data = File.ReadAllText(path);
links = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, LinkElement>>(data);
```